# The Silverlight SDK date picker isn't resetting the selected date to today

Tags: c#, silverlight, datepicker

I have the following definition for a `DatePicker`:

```xml
<sdk:DatePicker x:Name="dtpStartDate"
                Grid.Row="4"
                Grid.Column="1"
                SelectedDateFormat="Short"
                SelectedDate="{Binding MyObject.StartDate, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
```

`MyObject` is a class that contains the `StartDate` which is defined as a nullable `DateTime`.

```
class MyObjectClass
{
    ....
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

I'm using MVVM (via Prism) and `MyObject` is correctly bound.

The first time I display this view the date is blank (as expected) and when I click on the picker the calendar is displayed with today's date highlighted.

If I select a date (other than today) or display a record with a date filled then when I blank the form to create a new object:

```
this.MyObject = new MyObjectClass();
```

the date hightlighted when I click on the picker is the previously selected date.

So if the record showed "1st May 2009" that's what would be highlighted in the picker. I can set `StartDate` to `DateTime.Today` which is correctly displayed, but does mean that a date is displayed in the form which I don't want.

So, why doesn't setting the date to null reset the selected date in the picker to today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to reset the `DisplayDate` property on the `DatePicker`:

```
        this.SelectedDateChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (this.SelectedDate == null)
            {
                this.DisplayDate = DateTime.Today;
                this.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        };
```

*To add this functionality we had to subclass the `DataPicker` though.*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you just left this out from your question, but if you want programmatic changes to show up on the UI, your ViewModel and MyObjectClass
 should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  Specifically, the VM's MyObject property and MyObjectClass StartDate property setters should fire the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: Yeah - I just left it out. Everything implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. As I said setting the start date to `Today` updates it correctly.